# ¿Cómo decir "selfie" en castellano?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

Leí en Wikipedia una referencia a [**`autofoto`**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autofoto). Sin embargo, me parece un término algo "feo".

¿Existe una alternativa en español para la palabra `selfie` u otra forma de decirlo?

Comment: Según el twitter de #RAEConsultas https://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/440776281131872256, autofoto es correcto.

Comment: ¡Buena observación, @AlexBcn ! Podrías añadirlo como respuesta. Además -a todo el mundo- sería interesante ver si hay alguna otra palabra que pueda significar lo mismo. Y es que, insisto, a mí "autofoto" me suena fatal.

Comment: Una frase puede ser correcta y fea a la vez.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Según la RAE en un tuit [#RAEConsultas](http://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/440776281131872256) la palabra correcta es autofoto.
Como alternativa se menciona autoretrato.

Todo el mundo usa *selfie*/*selfi* así que a ver qué nos depara el futuro...

Extracto de una [entrevista de La Vanguardia a Pedro Álvarez de Miranda](http://www.lavanguardia.com/cultura/20141016/54417975191/nuevo-diccionario-rae-blaugrana-birra.html), académico director de la 23.ª edición del DRAE. Octubre del 2014

> *Y supongo que también es pronto para introducir ‘selfie’.*
>
> Esa es aún más pronto. En un coloquio un señor muy enfadado con la
>   palabra ‘selfie’ me decía que teníamos que adoptar la palabra
>   ‘autofoto’. Pues muy bien, a ver quién es el que consigue que autofoto
>   sea la que triunfe. Ni la Academia ni nadie puede gobernar los usos
>   léxicos de 400 y pico millones de personas. Y ‘selfie’ no ha habido
>   tiempo ni de considerarla.

Answer (score 2):

La Fundéu se ha ocupado un par de veces de esta palabra: primero para sugerir [autofoto](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/autofoto-alternativa-en-espanol-a-selfie/) y luego, como alternativa, la castellanización [selfi](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/selfi-adaptacion-al-espanol-de-selfie/).

Hay muchos precedentes en español para adaptaciones de este tipo; una de las más conocidas es la del inglés *football*, que ha dado en español tanto la traducción (*balompié*) como la adaptación ortográfica *fútbol*, que ha acabado siendo la más utilizada.

Dentro del ámbito futbolístico, también ocurrió lo mismo con el *offside*, que tuvo traducción (*fuera de juego*) como adaptación ortográfica (*orsay* u *orsai*); en este caso, sin embargo, ha sido la traducción la que ha acabado siendo más utliizada en algunos países como España (si bien creo que en otros, como Argentina, es más habitual *orsai*).

Toda esta discusión viene a decir que el uso es el que acaba llevando por un camino u otro, pero en este caso tenemos las dos posibilidades, de momento. Por cierto: yo he usado *autofoto* muchas veces, antes de que se pusiera de moda este tipo de autorretrato, así que no me parece una palabra fea :)

Answer (score -1):

Las lenguas latinas son por desgracia menos flexibles que el Inglés a la hora de acuñar neologismos. En Francia solían decir "ce week end" para decir "este fin de semana" porque "fin de la semaine" es trivialmente y obviamente demasiado largo.    Ocurrió algo bonito en España cuando se popularizó el término "finde" (fin de, todo junto) para decir lo mismo y aún más corto que "week end". Si tuviéramos más inspiraciones de esta índole; con buen gusto e inteligencia, rescataríamos al Español de la postración relativa, en cuanto a la capacidad de creación de palabras nuevas, en que se encuentra. Para ello hay que utilizar a la vez la audacia y el sentido del equilibrio. Yo crearía la siguiente palabra "yomism" para decir "selfie". La palabra "yomism" suena bien, es corta, y expresa bien, explícitamente, lo que quiere significar; con audacia, pero con equilibrio. La palabra iría muy bien para sustituir a "selfie".

Comment: Hay harto que opinar con respecto a tu respuesta, la cual se agradece. Yo voy en tu contra por lo siguiente: 1. Los neologismos nunca nacen por sugerencia, son procesos culturales. 2. El español es tremendamente creativo y flexible; surgen palabras nuevas, expresivas y útiles a cada rato. 3. Con respecto a  _selfie_, a la cultura latina le llegó el paquete completo [objeto-concepto-palabra]; no sé si la comunidad lingüística sienta la necesidad de crear una palabra nueva en este caso.