# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "lucir palmito"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, españa

En España solemos decir cosas como:

> A esa chica le encanta **lucir palmito**: siempre se está haciendo [autofotos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/14714/1674).
>
> ¡Ya he empezado la operación bikini! Este año quiero **lucir palmito** en la playa.

Es decir, utilizamos *lucir palmito* para designar el acto de mostrar el cuerpo de uno con satisfacción, vanagloriarse de lo bien puestas que están las carnes propias.

El DRAE recoge un par de entradas, pero me quedo con la segunda:

> [**palmito**<sup>2</sup>](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RaIcb0y%7CRaJNh2R)
>   Del dim. de palmo.
>   1. m. coloq. Cara de mujer.
>   2. m. coloq. Talle esbelto de la mujer.

Si bien la primera entrada indica:

> *como un palmito*
>   1. loc. adv. coloq. U. para dar a entender que alguien está curiosa y limpiamente vestido.

Siguiendo el hilo de palmito<sup>2</sup> llegamos a palmo:

> [**palmo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RaKOsnr)
>   Del lat. *palmus*.
>   1. m. Distancia que va desde el extremo del pulgar hasta el del meñique, estando la mano extendida y abierta.
>   2. m. Medida de longitud de unos 20 cm, que equivalía a la cuarta parte de una vara y estaba dividida en doce partes iguales o dedos.
>   3. m. palmo menor.
>   4. m. Juego de muchachos en que se tiran monedas contra una pared, y gana la moneda el que hace caer la suya a un palmo o menos de distancia de la del otro.

Pero parece que esta referencia me deja en un callejón sin salida: ninguna de las acepciones parece remotamente relacionada con la belleza, la figura o cosas similares.

Entonces, ¿cuál sería el origen de esta expresión? ¿Se usa también en regiones de Hispanoamérica?

Comment: Covarrubias ya recoge la acepción de palmito como el que lleva muchos ropajes, haciendo comparación con la planta del palmito y sus hojas. El de autoridades recoge ese sentido y el de cara de mujer, pero no da más explicaciones. Se me ocurre que la cara mide poco menos de un palmo de ancho, es decir, un palmo pequeño o palmito.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo se me ocurre alguna otra cosa que puede medir un palmo y a la gente le puede gustar lucirla... pero no, no voy a decirla :D Bromas aparte, la hipótesis suena convincente; lo curioso es que la evolución de la expresión la ha llevado a enmarcar todo el cuerpo, no solo la cara.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues parece que ha sido la convergencia de dos expresiones. Por un lado, tenemos la acepción de palmito como aquel que viste muchos ropajes, ya dada por Covarrubias en 1611:

> PALMITOS, redrojos de palma, cuya medula y hijuelos se comen. De uno que estâ con muchos vestidos, dezimos, que está vestido como un palmito.

El diccionario de Autoridades lo amplía a:

> Estar como un *palmito*. Phrase vulgár con que se dá à entender que alguno está curioso, y limpiamente vestido.

La acepción viene directamente por comparación con el árbol de palma y la forma de sus hojas. Por otro lado, tenemos "palmito" como diminutivo de palmo (palmo pequeño). También el diccionario de Autoridades nos da la siguiente definición:

> PALMITO. [...] Usase hablando del rostro, especialmente de las mugéres: y assi se dice buen palmito.

Esta expresión viene directamente dada por el tamaño que tiene la cara dentro del cuerpo: apenas un palmo. Esto se puede comprobar en [textos en el CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=palmo%20de%20cara&autor=&titulo=&ano1=1000&ano2=1700&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000) que hacen referencia a la expresión "un palmo de cara".

> *Este palmo de cara, amiga mía,
>
>   dio a un mercader tal guerra y batería
>
>   que, apoderado amor de sus entrañas,
>
>   pudo sacarme de vender castañas.*
>
> Alonso de Castillo Solórzano, "Aventuras del Bachiller Trapaza", 1637 (España)

Así pues, por un lado tenemos que un palmito es el rostro femenino hermoso, y por otro que es una forma curiosa de vestir. Si mezclamos ambos términos se llega a denominar a lo que hay debajo del vestido: el talle femenino. O puede simplemente que la expresión "buen palmito" se extendiera desde referirse a la cara a referirse al cuerpo entero, dado que esta acepción no se incorporó al diccionario hasta 1956. No sé cómo andarían los trajes femeninos de ceñidos por esa época (los de calle, no los de gala), pero seguramente bastante más que en el siglo XVII. En todo caso, conforme ha pasado el tiempo la mujer ha podido ir luciendo algo más que la cara, a medida que la sociedad ha ido avanzando y la mujer se ha ido liberando.