# ¿Por qué "palmar" es morir?

Tags: etimología, significado

Investigando para intentar responder a [**esta pregunta**](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19263/de-d%C3%B3nde-viene-la-expresi%C3%B3n-lucir-palmito) he encontrado que en el Diccionario de la Lengua aparece [**palmar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RZmjYFt) como

> 1. intr. coloq. Dicho de una persona: **morir** (‖ llegar al término de la vida).
>
> 3. tr. Nic. **matar** (‖ quitar la vida). U. t. c. prnl.
>
> palmarla
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. **morir** (‖ llegar al término de la vida).

Indicando en la etimología:

> Del lat. tardío *palmāre* 'dejar impresa la palma de la mano'

¿Cómo ha pasado el significado de "dejar impresa la palma de la mano"  a "morir, matar"?

Answer (score 6):

Ya desde la primera versión del diccionario (el de autoridades) del siglo XVIII, se dispone de la siguiente definición de "palmar":

> PALMAR. v.a. Voz de la Germanía, que significa dar por fuerza alguna cosa.

Esta acepción, que [se mantiene hoy día](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RZmjYFt), quiere decir que "palmar" es el acto de entregar algo sin que puedas hacer nada por evitarlo (por fuerza). Por tanto, el momento de entregar tu vida también es "palmar", o "palmarla" (palmar la vida).

Me imagino el origen de "palmar" como "pon algo en la palma abierta de tu mano para que yo lo pueda coger". A continuación os pongo un ejemplo de uso de este significado original:

> *Si godas Campanas crio,
>
>   el me las auia **palmado**:
>
>   dineros que al Padre deuo
>
>   por mi los tiene pagados.
>
>   Ni me pilla lo que tengo,
>
>   ni me espilla lo que gano:
>
>   assi dile a tu señor,
>
>   que se monte ya a lo largo.
>
>   Y busque otra que le **palme**,
>
>   que ya le he **palmado** harto:
>
>   y no venga por aca,
>
>   que le sera mal contado.*
>
> Anónimo, "Romances de germanía de varios autores [...]", 1609 (España)

Comment: Y yo convencido de que eso de "germanía" tenía algo que ver con Alemania: "La germanía es la jerga usada por presos, criminales, etc. El término _germania_ significa ‘hermandad’ en catalán (hermandades gremiales), y proviene de la palabra catalana _germà_, la cual tiene a su vez etimología en el latín _germānus_, que significa ‘hermano mayor’."

Comment: ¡Caramba! También yo estaba convencidísimo de lo de Germanía.

Comment: Lo que no parece cuadrar mucho con la etimología que indica la RAE: Del lat. tardío *palmāre* 'dejar impresa la palma de la mano'

Comment: @user esa es la etimología original de la palabra, lo que no quita para que en algún momento se le diera a esa misma palabra un significando diferente. La jerga de la germanía se basa precisamente en eso, en dar otros significados a palabras para construir su vocabulario propio, en ocasiones con intención de despistar a las autoridades.