# ¿Por qué se dice "quedarse con un palmo de narices"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, coloquialismos

Partiendo de [esta otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19263/12637), vemos que la palabra *palmo* como unidad de medida da lugar a varias expresiones:

- Quedarse *con un palmo de lengua fuera*, cuando se está muy cansado.
- No levantar alguien *un palmo del suelo*, cuando se es muy bajito.

Sin embargo, la que me intriga es la siguiente:

> [**dejar** a alguien **con un palmo de narices**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RaKOsnr#8YDI0tk)
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Chasquearlo, privándolo de lo que esperaba conseguir.

Se usa mucho esta expresión precisamente para eso, para indicar que alguien se ha quedado con las ganas de conseguir algo que deseaba, sobre todo cuando es en el último momento.

¿Por qué se dice así? ¿Qué tiene que ver el sentido del olfato con haberse quedado con las ganas de algo? ¿O, como indica la Wikipedia, tiene que ver con [el gesto de hacer burla](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palmo_de_narices)? En cualquier caso, ¿cuándo y cómo se originó la expresión?

[image: Palmo de narices]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el CORDE aparece *palmo de narices* con su sentido figurado actual (o similar) [en 1705](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=1&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=0&FID=260217%5C023%5CC003O26022017231830858.1172.1168&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20palmo%20de%20narices%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto1) y luego [en 1769](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=2&ordenar1=3&ordenar2=0&FID=260217%5C023%5CC003O26022017231830858.1172.1168&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20palmo%20de%20narices%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto2), ambos con la aclaración "como dicen", que sugiere que la expresión todavía requería alguna aclaración. En la primera de estas citas da la impresión de que el significado es de "verse impedido" más que de "ser víctima de un chasco":

> …abrió la puerta por cumplimiento, pero no quiso dejar entrar ninguno
>   porque estaba dentro. Con que se volvieron a salir, con un palmo de
>   narices como dicen…

Dado que la expresión en cuestión parece tener una larga historia, fui a buscar a ver si encontraba algo similar en el portugués. Me encontré con que

- *ficar com nariz de palmo e meio* significa "[quedar decepcionado](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/nariz)", "[no obtener lo que se quería](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/ficar%20com%20nariz%20de%20palmo%20e%20meio/)";
- *nariz comprido* (literalmente "nariz larga") es "[estado de frustración o decepción](http://www.aulete.com.br/nariz)" y *ficar de nariz comprido* significa también "[errar el tiro](http://www.wordreference.com/ptes/nariz)".

Está claro que hay una relación entre las expresiones de ambas lenguas.

¡Pero hay más! La misma expresión exacta aparece también en italiano: *con un palmo di naso*, que según el Wikcionario significa *deluso e allibito*, o sea, "frustrado y atónito, desilusionado y desconcertado", etc. De manera que ya van tres lenguas romances con una expresión equivalente.

A esta altura tampoco me sorprendió encontrar que en francés *[faire un long nez](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-synonymes/faire%20un%20long%20nez)* ("hacer una nariz larga") significa "estar decepcionado o contrariado".

El gesto de burla con las manos referenciado en la Wikipedia en español como posible origen de la expresión "palmo de narices" se llama en francés *[pied de nez](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pied_de_nez)* (*pied* = pie, unidad de medida). *Faire un pied de nez* significa "burlar" y no parece que tenga relación directa con *faire un nez long*, pero no creo extraño imaginar que una haya influido en la otra.

No tengo una respuesta clara para concluir, pero imagino que el par de expresiones francesas, asociadas, pudieron haber llevado a un doblete como el que hoy existe en español:

```
 dejar a alguien \
                  |- con un palmo de narices
        quedarse /
```

Comment: También existe en catalán: "quedar-se amb un pam de nas" o "deixar a algú amb un pam de nas".

Answer (score 0):

¿No será que la asociación de la nariz larga con el deseo insatisfecho proviene de alguna metáfora de dicha parte de la cara por otro órgano que tiende a permanecer tieso cuando se queda con las ganas?

Sí, ya sé que llego seis años tarde, pero me sorprende que nadie lo haya sugerido.