# ¿De donde sale la expresión «de tres pares de narices»? ¿Dónde se usa?

Tags: expresiones

La reciente recomendación de Fundéu sobre [sindiós](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/un-sin-dios-sindios/) la hacen respondiendo a la pregunta

> Cuando algo es un jaleo de tres pares de narices, ¿está bien decir que es un sin Dios?

Al buscar sobre «tres pares de narices» encuentro ejemplos como:

> hace un calor *de tres pares de narices*.

Con esa y varias consultas creo entender que el sentido de la frase es expresar algo exagerado pero lo que no entiendo es de dónde sale esa expresión. ¿pares? ¿pares de narices? ¿tres?.

¿De donde sale la expresión «de tres pares de narices»?

¿Dónde se usa esta expresión?

Comment: Mi conjetura es que "narices" es una suerte de "["minced oaths"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/29047/5481) para "cojones" (fíjate que decimos "no me toques las narices", pero no "no me toques la nariz", o la oreja para el caso). Entonces tiene un poco más de sentido que hablemos de algo que viene a pares (que las narices no lo hacen). Lo de que sean tres en lugar de cinco o siete lo atribuyo a la casualidad o a la sonoridad (igual que el quinto pino podría haber sido el séptimo...). Así "[...] de tres pares de narices" es la forma no "blasfema" de "[...] de tres pares de cojones".

Comment: @Diego Tiene sentido lo que expones. Creo que sería una respuesta válida. Una puntualización, el DRAE recoge que nariz también es "cada uno de los DOS orificios que hay en la base de la nariz", es decir que sí vienen a pares. Además señala que "de narices" es equivalente a "de dos pares de narices". Como indicas, se interpreta igual poniendo cojones en lugar de narices, aunque al restar blasfemia, se resta también contundencia y sonoridad.

Comment: [Hablando de narices...](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19640/12637)

Comment: @Diego estoy de acuerdo. Seguramente será el mismo eufemismo que cuando decimos "me estás hinchando las narices" para expresar enfado. Por cierto, en la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de España veo casos de "tres pares de narices" desde 1867: "Ya voy viendo que el asunto tiene tres pares de narices".

Comment: @Charlie ¿1867? ¿así de antigua es la cosa? Muy interesante.

Comment: @Diego no se me pasó por la mente lo de «Hace un calor de tres pares de cojones».tal vez por que nunca he escuchado esta expresión y solo la vi escrita por primera vez ayer en Fundéu. Tal vez al escuchársela a alguien con una buena entonación sea obvio lo de narices por cojones. Gracias.

Comment: La verdad es que no es muy obvio. Yo mismo tenía la duda de si "está delante de mis **narices**" estaba mal dicho, porque nariz solo tenemos una. Pero al empezar a redactar una pregunta y ver la entrada del DLE vi que tiene una nota (de esas que se leen mal porque son todo abreviaturas) que dice que puede ser usada en plural con el mismo significado que en singular. Vamos, que en mi cara hay "unas narices" Cuantas? Pues solo una, pero son "narices" a la vez que "nariz". ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ En fin. Que tiene narices la cosa...

Comment: Is there any chance that _narices_ is an attempt to fill the apparent gap in Spanish for a word for the English nostril. When I first read the title of this post I assumed nostrils was intended but some research reveals only a phrase for nostril not a single word.

Comment: @mdewey see [narina](https://dle.rae.es/narina). You and I learned something today.

Comment: @wimi well that is good news. The idea that hispanophones were doomed never to be able to talk of their nostrils was sad. My researches on Wikipedia had failed to find narina.

Comment: @mdewey I would not bet on random Spanish speakers understanding the word *narina* if you use it on them. It did take me a while to find it...

Answer (score 1):

A clue to the possible source/origin of the expression might also be this:

https://artsandculture.google.com/asset/trifacial-trinity-anonymous-cusco-school/nwGOfzqyUQzmpQ

> ...the Viceregal church sought to explain to the faithful the mystery of the Holy Trinity, so crucial to Christian doctrine. In this case, the image has medieval origins, transmitted through engravings. The Catholic dogma which affirms the existence of three different persons in a single God is expressed here as a face with four eyes, three noses and three mouths.
>
> [image]
>
> El dogma católico que afirma la existencia de tres personas distintas en un solo Dios, toma aquí la forma de un rostro con cuatro ojos, tres narices y tres bocas.

The word "narices" has also another variant namely "napias" which means "big nose/s"

> "QUÉ SIGNIFICA NAPIAS EN ESPAÑOL
> En el diccionario castellano napias significa narices, órgano de la cara humana, especialmente cuando es muy grande."

Source https://educalingo.com/es/dic-es/napias

If "de tres pares de narices" means "the Holy Trinity", then "de tres pares de napias" must mean something bigger than that, or that one received something more than expected.
A search on the internet for the expression "De tres pares de napias" shows 120 hits.

Comment: Well, this is not a comment, this is an answer. Thank you for registering. Please don't hesitate to use this resource to improve your Spanish. Also, check [help], [tour] and [answer]. If you want to post this as a comment, flag for moderation attention and they will take care of converting your contribution from answer to comment. You need 10 reputation or so to earn the privilege of commenting. Check https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges