# Relación de Jeme con el rostro femenino

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones

Recordando hoy la palabra *[Jeme](https://dle.rae.es/jeme?m=form)*, se me hizo extraña su segunda acepción, que remite a *Palmito (2) con los siguientes significados:

> 1. m. coloq. Cara de mujer.
> 2. m. coloq. Talle esbelto de la mujer.

La etimología no ayuda mucho (*semis* en latín) y desde internet el único sitio que encontré tampoco me colaboró mucho. En el documento [De mujeres y diccionarios](https://www.ub.edu/portal/documents/6247957/0/2004DeMujeresyDiccionariosEvolucionFemenino.pdf/3ec66caa-bcf9-db71-6d10-e09858e89076) se menciona el término en la página 53 y 144, sin llegar a aclarar que tiene que ver el jeme con el rostro o el talle de la mujer (aclara que la palabra se usa para belleza, pero no desde cuando ni porqué)

Comment: [Aquí está la respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/19639/19361)

Comment: @Danielillo en la respuesta que enlazas se hace la conexión entre la palabra "palmito" y sus significados. En esta pregunta se pide la conexión entre "jeme" y "palmito".

Comment: Si ese es el caso no creo que tenga demasiado sentido la pregunta. Las relaciones etimológicas entre sinónimos es prácticamente inexistente. Es lo mismo que preguntar cuál es la relación entre *casa* y  *vivienda* más allá de ser simples sinónimos.

Comment: @Danielillo, habitualmente la etimología te ayuda a comprender el significado de algunas palabras. En efecto este NO es el motivo, solo lo mencioné para dejar en claro que intenté buscar por esa parte y no me funcionó

Comment: Entiendo tu pregunta, no el comentario que habla de conexión etimológica entre "jeme" y "palmito". Son dos sinónimos sin más. By the way, tampoco conocía la palabra *jeme*. La palabra *palmito* referida al cuerpo sí que la conozco, pero es de uso bastante antiguo: – El próximo sábado a la noche sacaré a ventilar el palmito –   Por cierto, se aplica tanto a hombre como a mujer.